# How to Add child node in Treeview in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a Treeview in silverlight Page.Now i have to Add the node to child of every node programatically in Treeview.How can i do this?

My code is like this

```
 TreeViewItem item1 = new TreeViewItem();
 item1.Header = "Products";
 item1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Media Players" });
 item1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Games" });
 item1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Charts" });
 MyTreeView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

Now this will give me output like this

```
Products
   Media Players    
   Games
   Charts
```

But I want output like this

```
Products
   Media Players 
      Games
         Charts
```

Means have to Add node to child of newly created node..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
    var products = new TreeViewItem {Header = "Products"};
    var mediaPlayers = new TreeViewItem() {Header = "Media Players"};
    var charts = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Charts" };
    var games = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Games" };

    products.Items.Add(mediaPlayers);
    mediaPlayers.Items.Add(games);
    games.Items.Add(charts);

MyTreeView1.Items.Add(products);
```